# Filtering data with Pandas.query() method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, database, dataframe

I want to filter product_type which is having "others" for all ticket_id and replace "others" with voice.

Sample dataframe

```
ticket_id  network  product_type

123        AAA      tv
345        AAA      others       
567        BBB      others
678        CCC      others
789        DDD      broad
```

Expected output

```
ticket_id  network  product_type

123        AAA      tv
345        AAA      voice       
567        BBB      voice
678        CCC      voice
789        DDD      broad
```

I tried the below function but it gives an error:

**ERROR:root:The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().**

```
def product_mapping(df):
    try:
        data = df.query('product_type == "others"')['ticket_id']
        if data:
            data["product_type"] = data["product_type"].replace({"others": "voice"})
            return data
        else:
            return df
    except Exception as error:
        logger.error(error)
```

Comment: `df.query('product_type == "others"')`?

Comment: @Timus Yup, I tried with this, but it's giving another error. Please refer my updated code above.

Comment: I think you wanna filter the t`icket_id` if the `product_type` is other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
df['product_type'] = df.product_type.str.replace('others', 'voice')
```

Output:

```
ticket_id   network product_type
0   123 AAA tv
1   345 AAA voice
2   567 BBB voice
3   678 CCC voice
4   789 DDD broad
```

You can check if 'others' exist in `product_type` by:

```
if 'others' in df.product_type.tolist():
    #there is 'others' in product_type
else:
    #there is no 'others' in product_type
```

Comment: Thanks much! Can we get this through a function? if it is product with "others" then return voice else it should get the dataframe.

Comment: @bdfrd I have one doubt, why are you converting to list ? Any specific reason. I tried without tolist(), but if statement is not working.

Comment: No. That works but it returns false because it chevks whether “others” exist in indexes.

Answer (score 0):

```
def mapping(df):
    try:
        if 'others' in df.product.tolist():
            df["product"] = df["product"].replace(['others'],'voice')  
            return df
        else:
            return df
        
    except Exception as error:
        logger.error(error)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).